# Django MultiSelectField with multiple fields per choice

Tags: django, multi-select

I'm using [MultiSelectField](https://pypi.org/project/django-select-multiple-field/) in my form, which allows the user to select multiple choices:

**models.py**

```
physical_limits = MultiSelectField('Physical Limitations', choices=PHYSICAL_LIMIT, max_length=255)
```

[screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1x6jP.png)

However, I would like to add few additional fields per choice, e.g. min value, max value, units, etc (for the user to fill in, for each choice he makes).

For example, if the user selects option (2), which is "Solid", he will then be able to fill in additional corresponding "sub-fields" for this selection.

In some way, I feel like I'm looking for a different field type, which acts more like a table or array, for the user to fill. I couldn't find such a thing though..

["Vision"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1tVH.png)

Can you please guide me how to achieve that goal?

Thanks ahead,
Shahar

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you're trying to do? I appreciate the link but I'm just guessing how you're using it.

Comment: Sure, I've just edited my question with some more info, thanks

Comment: To be clear, you're limiting the initial choice to just one, but after that it is multi-select? Or can the first choice be multi select also?

Comment: Hi Scott, the user may make multiple-selections among Powdery, Solid, etc. (= PHYSICAL_LIMIT choices). That boolean behavior is already obtained by the MultiSelectField class. I would like the user to be able of filling in additional fields per each selection he makes. For example, if he chooses "Solid", then he will also provide additional information that corresponds to "Solid", e.g. min limit, max limit, units, etc. (each one is a 'Field')